# How do I show that $B \to A \oplus C$ where $b \mapsto (p(b), j(b))$ is surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, exact-sequence

From Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*:

> [image]
>
> How do I show that $B \to A \oplus C$ where $b \mapsto (p(b), j(b))$ is surjective?

I can show that this map is well-defined and we use the fact that $\ker (j) = Im(i)$ to show that it is injective. However, I can't seem to show that it is surjective.

---

I know that $i(a) \mapsto (p(i(a), j(i(a))=(a,0)$. So, I need to figure out what maps to $(0,c)$.

Comment: Have you checked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma? The diagram chase done there may give you some inspiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b \in j^{-1}(c)$. So, $j(b)=c$. Thus, $b-ip(b) \mapsto (p(b-ip(b)), j(b-ip(b)))= (0, c).$

So, $i(a)+b-ip(b) \mapsto (a,c)$.